# Filtering data in UI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

The filter using below code is not working. I created an application using a template from Web IDE and then bound OData to the list in XMLView, applying filter on search.

View:

```
<SearchField liveChange="onSearch" id="master1SearchField" search="onSearch"/>  
<List id="master1List" items="{path:'/DetailsSet'}">
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem id="master1ListItem">
            <attributes>
                <ObjectAttribute text="{Name}"/>                            
            </attributes>
        </ObjectListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

Controller:

```
onSearch : function(oEvent) {
    var sFilteredValue = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
    var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sFilteredValue);
    var oElement = this.getView().byId("table");
    var oBinding = oElement.getBinding("items");
    oBinding.filter([oFilter]);             
}
```

Comment: Are you applying the filter on the correct control? The ID of your `oElement` is `"table"` whereas the list has the ID `"master1List"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter with "or“ and "and" conditions on multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433200/filter-with-or-and-and-conditions-on-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get binding of the items on which the filter need to be applied.

```
var oElement = this.getView().byId("master1List");
```

should resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to force an update of the control after setting the filter:

```
oBinding.refresh(true);
```