# Filter with "OR" And "AND" Conditions on Multiple Fields

Tags: sapui5

I want to implement the below *where* condition. How do I create the filter in UI5?

`field-A NE 'O' and ( field-B contains 'search-text' or field-C contains 'search-text' )`

The backend business scenario:

1. Apply the filter `field-A NE 'O'` when binding list.
2. Apply the filter `( field-B contains 'search-text' or field-C contains 'search-text' )` to implement the search function on the search field.

Filter instances:

```
new sap.ui.model.Filter("field-A", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE, "O");
new sap.ui.model.Filter("field-B", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.contains, search-text);
new sap.ui.model.Filter("field-C", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.contains, search-text);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of combining multiple filters using OData from Northwind: https://embed.plnkr.co/AoIZI4/. The complete list can be found [here](http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$format=json).

When instantiating a filter, instead of `path`, `operator`, and `value1`, use the properties `filters` and `and` to combine multiple filters as shown in the [`Filter` API reference](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter).

In our case, we define three filters:

- One for the first `field-A NE 'O'` which is also used on the initial binding in the Plunker example above (Filter 1)
- And for the other two in the search event handler with `and: false` meaning `OR` (Filter 2).

**Filter 1:**

```js
getInitialFilter: function() {
  return new Filter("Field-A", FilterOperator.NE, "O");
},
```

Tip: an "initial filter" can be also specified in XML directly when defining the aggregation binding. Refer to "Multiple Filters in XML" https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561773/5846045.

**Filter 2:**

```js
getSearchFilters: function(query) {
  return new Filter({
    filters: [
      new Filter("Field-B", FilterOperator.Contains, query),
      new Filter("Field-C", FilterOperator.Contains, query),
    ],
    and: false,
  });
},
```

Finally, when the user enters a search query, we combine those two filters with `and: true` applying on the [ODataListBinding](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding/methods/filter).

```js
onSearch: function(event) {
  this.byId("myList").getBinding("items").filter(new Filter({
    filters: [
      this.getInitialFilter(),
      this.getSearchFilters(event.getParameter("query")),
    ],
    and: true,
  }), FilterType.Application);
},
```

---

**Note:** depending on the use case, ensure passing the [FilterType](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.FilterType) `Application` as a 2nd argument when calling `myListBinding.filter` to let the framework know that the filter was set **by you** (the application) and not by a control. According to the linked FilterType API reference:

> Each list binding maintains two separate lists of filters: one for filters defined by the control that owns the binding, and another list for filters that an application can define in addition. When executing the filter operation, **both sets of filters are combined.**

By default:

- `v2.ODataListBinding#filter` uses the FilterType `Control` (might not be what you want).
- `v4.ODataListBinding#filter` uses the FilterType `Application`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var andFilter = [];

var orFilter = [];

orFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("title", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Equal, "filtervalue"));

orFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("status", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Equal, "filtervalue"));

andFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter(orFilter, false));

orFilter = [];

orFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("title", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Equal, "filtervalue1"));

orFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("status", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Equal, "filtervalue1"));

andFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter(orFilter, false));

oBinding.filter(new sap.ui.model.Filter(andFilter, true));
```

That should translate to:

```
title=filtervalue || status=filtervalue && title=filtervalue1 || status=filtervalue1
```

Comment: is it really "title=filtervalue || status=filtervalue && title=filtervalue1 || status=filtervalue1" or is it result "(title=filtervalue || status=filtervalue) && (title=filtervalue1 || status=filtervalue1)" ?

Answer (score 1):

Use below syntax for multiple filter with OR condition: (change false to true for AND)

```
var InputFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
  filters: [
    new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, inptval),
    new sap.ui.model.Filter("ID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, inptval)
  ],
  and: false
});

this.oModel.read("/Products", {
  filters: [InputFilter],
  success: jQuery.proxy(this._fnSuccessGet, this),
  error: jQuery.proxy(this._fnErrorGet, this)
});
```