# Multiple Filters in XML

Tags: sapui5

So I have a list but I want to filter out the type if its `'05'` or `'01'` to not display in the list. The following code work fine for `'05'` but not `'01'`. How would I write it to add another value?

```
items="{
  path: 'Entries',
  filters: [{
    path: 'Type',
    operator : 'NE',
    value1 : '05',
    value2: '01'
  }]
}"
```

I tried this which I would assume is the logical way, but it then started displaying both 05 and 01. So I assume this is using an *OR* filter rather than filter *AND* filter combined.

```
items="{
  path:'Entries',
  filters: [{
    path: 'Type',
    operator: 'NE',
    value1: '05'
  }, {
    path: 'Type',
    operator: 'NE',
    value1: '01'
  }]
}
```

Comment: Does the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561773/5846045) below solve the problem? Feel free to leave a comment there if something is unclear.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the syntax in XML view:

```
items="{
  path: '/Products',
  filters: [
    {
      filters: [
        {
          path: 'ProductName',
          operator: 'StartsWith',
          value1: 'Sir '
        },
        {
          path: 'Discontinued',
          operator: 'EQ',
          value1: false
        },
      ],
      and: true
    }
  ]
}"
```

Working example: https://embed.plnkr.co/wAlrHB?show=view/Home.view.xml,preview

The parameter `filters` awaits an array of filter info objects. A filter info object is constrained in the following combinations of properties:

- `path`, `operator`, `value1` (and `value2` if applicable)
- Or `filters` and `and`. <-- This is what we need.

API reference: [`sap.ui.model.Filter`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter/constructor)

---

The reason, why your second approach didn't work, is because both filters were pointing to the same path (`'Type'`) which results in OR logic.

> All filters applied to a single table column are ORed, while filters on different table columns are ANDed. Please either use the automatic grouping of filters (where applicable) or use explicit AND/OR filters, a mixture of both is not supported. [[source]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.ListBinding/methods/filter)

Comment: can I have multiple filters? I need basically somehow to "create" an OR by having then two filters where I have a different value in the end

Comment: @Nali In the sample above, if you set `and: false`, then the two filter properties `ProductName` and `Discontinued` are performed with an OR. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes from what you copied from the documentation the and: true in your original post is actually obsolete right? Because it is two different paths they are ANDed anyway. Now if they would be two times ProductName in your filter they would be ORed and if you want them to be ANDed you have to add your and: true did I understand this correctly?

Comment: To use the working example, go to the proxy "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" and accept the temporary access to avoid CORS issues. After that, you can rerun the app in plnkr.co

Answer (score 1):

The `value2` parameter to use with [`sap.ui.model.Filter`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter) is only valid with some [`sap.ui.model.FilterOperators`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator) such as `BT`. To work around this we can set up multiple `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE` filters, in your case filtering the property `"Type"` for values 1 and 2.

By default if you combine many filters together, they are logically grouped with `OR`, that makes sense when you do the `EQ` filter but not for the `NE` filter where you have to use `AND`. Luckily the [`sap.ui.model.Filter`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter) class has a parameter that let's us define this.

---

In my example I have an [`sap.m.Table`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.Table) that has a binding to the following "Fruits" object:

```
var Fruits = {
   "Fruits": [{
     "id": "1",
     "name": "Apple"
    }, {
     "id": "2",
     "name": "Blueberry"
    }, {
     "id": "3",
     "name": "Cranberry"
    }]
};
```

And just like in your question, I want to filter both `"id"` 1 and 2 out of my table. This can be achieved by the following method:

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("idListFruits");
oTable.getBinding("items").filter(new Filter({
   filters: [
     new Filter({
         filters: [
             new Filter("id", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE, "1"),
             new Filter("id", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE, "2")
         ], and: true
     })
   ]
}));
```

This way I can apply both `NE` filters to my table and  also set the `AND` parameter to true indicating that an "AND" logical conjunction is applied on the filters.

My table output:

[image: My fruits table without both ids 1 and 2[4]]

Comment: Thanks Andre, I knew I could do it above in the controller, I'm trying to find a simple solution to do it in a list items in xml.