# Can the initial OData load be disabled in a SAPUI5 app?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

SAPUI5 freestyle app using OData v2 and two-way binding.

How do I disable the OData request on page load ?

For example, by default I want there to be no results shown in a List, then when the user choses a filter (or show all), the OData is retrieved.

In Fiori elements, there's an initialLoad property that can be set to enable/disable the loading of OData on a page load. How can this be achieved in a freestyle app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OData Tree binding with filters in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224382/odata-tree-binding-with-filters-in-a-fragment)

Comment: Basically you can create the binding as usual in the XML view but set it to `suspended`. Then once you filter you can call `resume` on the binding. Imo this is cleaner than creating templates in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is here...

Basically don't bind the items aggregation in the view, bind it manually in the controller:

https://answers.sap.com/questions/13778637/can-the-initial-odata-load-be-disabled-in-a-sapui5.html